# CodeIgniter URL Encryption

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am new in Codeigniter. I want to encrypt full URL like below example.

For example this is my url [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) & my controller is home, so full url is [www.example.com/home](http://www.example.com/home)

Now I want to encrypted all controller, function like below

```
www.example.com/5115784bef2514430e7f74d9a71d4142a942efb0f7cc428626bda7633326f9d015fbacc60d93cd6b858f9b6e05c1e56263acb24297cecc720467eb4f222d81e5hdn5B
```

I can encrypt and decrypt the text well, but I just don't get how I can decrypt from url & make understand which controller or function is called, I want to decrypted everything after base_url.

Please don't suggest using a common controller, because I already know that & any how common controller hides everything so it's not required for the encryption I believe.

Answer (score 0):

Well i never encrypt any URL before but you can use a php function [url_encode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php)

And "str_replace" function.

the reason for using "str_replace" beacause  url_encode only encode special character in URL.

Hope I help some.

Try the code below.

urlencode(str_replace("your_domain.com/YourCOntrollerName/YourMethodName" , "SM5ah52" , yor_domain.com . "YourCOntrollerName/YourMethodName/YOuData"));

If not this. There is an library in CI Framework called Encryption.
You can get help from there [Encryption](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/encryption.html).

Answer (score 0):

Go with [URI Routing](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html) and define one controller to decode whatever you are passing, and call proper controller / method from it.

Comment: Somehow its means that I must have to use one common controller?

Comment: one controller to redirect "traffic" among others. or you can do some kind of encryption which allows  you to split it between many controllers. for example if first character of link is A -> direct traffic to controller A, and so on... multiple solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [URI Routing](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html#regular-expressions) with regular expressions.

```
$route["other_controllers/method"] = "other_controllers/method"; //you can add this kind of lines to not to affect other controllers
$route["([a-zA-Z0-9]+)"] = "home/decrypt/$1";
```

In the home controller, You can

1. Redirect to the page

Or

2. Load a view

```
public function decrypt($token){
   //geting the page according to the token from database.
   $desired_page = $this->some_model->get_page($token);

   //if you want to redirect
   redirect($desired_page);

   //if you want to load a view
   $this->load->view($desired_page);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for mentioning proper way but, Somehow its means that I must have to use one common controller to decode, right?

Comment: I didn't get this - `common controller its hide everything so its not required the encryption`. As I know, There could be only one gateway to decrypt the string.